# Why Does ArcGIS 10.8 See My Int As a Double

Tags: arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I am using AppendEvent_locref to spatialize data from a view into a feature class. In the feature class, the field is an int.  The view pulls the problematic field from the source table as a bigint, so in the view, I convert it to an int.

[image]

TSQL (using sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set) sees this field as an int with a precision of 10, size of 4, and scale of 0 (as expected).

[image]

According to ArcGIS, a field should only be promoted if the precision is greater than 10; yet, using ArcMap, this field is regarded as a double precision 19.

[image]

Does anyone know why it does this?
And, how do I get ArcGIS (specifically arcpy) to see it as the int it is supposed to be?